# Java regex matcher pattern keep returning false

Tags: java

I was having some problem with regex in Java. I have this regex pattern:

```
static Pattern parts = Pattern.compile("\\A([91|10|17|21|30].{1,20}\\s){1,5}\\Z");
```

Then I try to test it with dummy data:

```
String s = "91448629517150623101408002301";
Matcher testMatcher = parts.matcher(s);
System.out.println(testMatcher.matches());

String s1 = "9143676601715Sep14101310147301";
Matcher testMatcher1 = parts.matcher(s1);
System.out.println(testMatcher1.matches());
```

The dummy data is in the correct format. However, I not sure why both keep returns me false. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression you provided might be incorrect for matching the pattern. I think you might want to use **\s** (*A whitespace character*) instead of **\S** (*A non-whitespace character*).

I suggest you go through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) again carefully.

For example,

```
static Pattern parts = Pattern.compile("\\A([91|10|17|21|30].{1,20}\\S){1,5}\\Z");
```

Comment: Hey sorry just a quick check, let's say for the part 1 regex right, I wanted to get the string between '91' and '17', how should I modify the regex pattern?

Comment: You can refer the part regarding [capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg).

For example,  
 
`Pattern part = Pattern.compile("\\A91(\\d*)17(\\d*)\\Z");`  
`String s = "91448629517150623101408002301";`  
`Matcher testMatcher = part1.matcher(s);`  
`System.out.println("group 1: " + testMatcher.group(1));`

Comment: Hey may I check with you, by using the original code right, I tried with "914486295 17150623 101408002 301", how come it does not work when there is a white space?